# Getting information from .xml

Tags: xml, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter library which I use to load a xml file

using simplexml_load_file();

How ever I can get all the cdata information on the xml file but I cannot get the name="" from xml

How can I get the correct name="" from xml

`<file name="controllers/Test.php">`

Full XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<modification>
    <file name="controllers/Test.php"> <!-- need to get this name=""-->
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[class Test extends CI_Controller {]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[public function __construct() {}]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Var Dump Of simplexml_load_file()

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[16]
  public 'file' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[17]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'name' => string 'controllers/Test.php' (length=20)
      public 'operation' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[18]
          public 'search' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[19]
              ...
          public 'add' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[20]
              ...
```

MY Library

```
<?php

class Mod_xml {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->run();
    }

    public function run() {
        $file = APPPATH . 'third_party/mods/mods_test.xml';

        $x = simplexml_load_file($file);

        var_dump($x);

        // It should some how get <file name="get this content"> 
        //$name = ;

        $search_for_code = $x->file->operation->search;

        $add = $x->file->operation->add;

        $get_the_main_file_contents = file_get_contents(APPPATH . 'controllers/Test.php');

        $new_file_data = str_replace("$search_for_code", "$add", $get_the_main_file_contents);

        if (!file_exists(APPPATH . 'controllers/backup/Test.php')) {
            @copy(APPPATH . 'controllers/Test.php', APPPATH . 'controllers/backup/Test.php');
        }

        if(strpos($get_the_main_file_contents, "$search_for_code") !== FALSE){
            file_put_contents(APPPATH . 'controllers/Test.php', $new_file_data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out how Very simple solution

```
$file = APPPATH . 'third_party/mods/mods_test.xml';

$x = simplexml_load_file($file);

echo $x->file['name'];
```